# swipeUp() on XCUIApplication breaks the XCUIApplication in UITest

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xctest

We got a test where we need to `swipeUp` to see a cell inside of a `tableView`. After the `swipeUp` we cant event print out the `app.tables`. If we do not swipe everything works as expected.

- So what has changed in Swift 3 compared to Swift 2 here?
- How do we fix that issue?

Example:

```
func testSomethingInApp() {
   let app = XCUIApplication()
   app.launch()
   app.swipeUp() //after this we cant get app.tables anymore. Befor everything is fine
   XCTAssertEqual(app.tables.cells.elementBoundByIndex(5), "something") //something like this
}
```

Comment: What is the output of the error from the console? Any debug logs?

Comment: Sadly no other informations you just get thrown in assambler code. After the `swipeUp()` you cant even `po app.tables`. It'll end in assambler code.

Comment: can you please confirm that swipe gesture message should be send through `app` or through `app.tables` ?

Comment: instead of app.swipe(), have you tried swiping using the element like app.table["tour table"].swipeUp or using any visible element at that time?

Comment: Yes i have tried `app.tables.element(boundBy: 0).swipeUp()` which causes the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode 9 and Swift 4.0 does fix this issue. `app.swipeUp()` doesn't clear the tableview queried elements anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Try to access your element directly... `app.staticText["something"]`

When I wrote my UITests, I had some issues like these. 
I searched for the elements, putting breakpoints, and reading the output.

Print `app` in console using `po app` command.

---

[image]

---

Read the output, search for the element you want, see its type (if is a staticText, button, otherElements, whatever...)

---

[image]

---

See that all the elements available are displayed in output. 
The first word of each line in output is the type of each element.

In your code, access the type using: `app.buttons` to buttons, `app.staticTexts` to labels, etc...

JLU

Comment: I did that. As mentioned  the tableview is not present anymore whenever I swipe on whatever element. It doesn't matter if I take a different element then `app`. So even if I swipe somewhere else the tableview is not accessible anymore.